# How to send arguments to another screen? Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to send the arguments of a "participant" to another screen, I could do it with a ListView and load the list of events, but it is not working in the same way with the participants, now if the list works, but when I tap and I want to see the info of the "participant" everything comes out in null:

In this part I create the participant and generate the list to be able to visualize it, and by giving the tap I send the info of this (according to me)

```
        Widget _crearListadoParticipantes() {
      return FutureBuilder<List<Participantes>>(
        future: eventosProvider.cargarParticipantes(evento, participantes),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
            final participantes = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: participantes.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i], evento);
              }
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError){
            return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
          } else {  
            return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      );
    }

    Widget _crearParticipante(BuildContext context, Participantes participantes, EventoModel evento) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: RichText(
            softWrap: false,
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: "Lato_LightItalic",
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
              ),
              children: [
                TextSpan(text: '     '+'${participantes.numero}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                  )
                ),
                TextSpan(text: "           "),
                TextSpan(text: '${participantes.apellido} ${participantes.nombre}',)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'destalleParticipante', arguments: evento),
        ),
      );
    }
```

And this is where I am supposed to receive the arguments of the participant to whom I tapped, but as I say, a null returns

```
    class DetalleParticipante extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      _DetalleParticipanteState createState() => _DetalleParticipanteState();
    }

    class _DetalleParticipanteState extends State<DetalleParticipante> {

      final eventosProvider = new EventosProvider();

      EventoModel evento = new EventoModel();
      Participantes participantes = new Participantes();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        final EventoModel eventoData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        if ( eventoData != null ) {
          evento = eventoData;
        }
          print(participantes.nombre);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF249FE2),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body:  Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _encabezadoParticipante(context, AssetImage("assets/icon/info_corredor.png"), participantes, evento),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _backBottom() {
return FloatingActionButton(
  elevation: 0.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back,
    size: 45.0,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  onPressed: (){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
);
```

}

```
      Widget _encabezadoParticipante(BuildContext context, AssetImage image, Participantes participantes, EventoModel evento) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                _backBottom(),
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('${participantes.apellido}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      softWrap: true,
                      style: TextStyle(                
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Lato",
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Image(image: image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, Did you check the Cookbook in the documentation? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: My friend, I did it, and it worked with a certain part of the project, but in this case it doesn't

Comment: Could you provide all the content from the 'destalleParticipante' class?

Comment: Ready, I already added it

Comment: you mean that `eventoData` is `null` even though you are sure that `arguments: evento` is not `null`?

Comment: I am sure that it is not because when debugging I get null it is on the "detalleParticipante" page

Comment: add `print('evento: $evento');` before calling `pushNamed` method and `print('eventoData: $eventoData');` after calling `ModalRoute.of`, what do you see?

Comment: Great, to use the `settings.arguments` in that way you have to use a route config right? Probably you are using a onGenerateRoute config, if that is the case do this:  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute, But, let's confirm it, please provide the route config in your MaterialApp.

Comment: @pskink When adding the prints, this returns me:
event: Instance of 'EventModel'
eventData: Instance of 'EventModel'

I also added a print of "participant.name" and I returned null

Comment: @LuisMiguelMantilla If I use an already configured network where it is supposed to receive the arguments of the "participant" to whom I tap

Comment: No one has any idea how to help me? 

Comment: In your case, you have to use this: 
`MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    'destalleParticipante': (context) => DetalleParticipante(),
  },
);`

If you are using a onGenerateRoute and your own configuration file like this `onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute` , instead of routes that is the problem.

Comment: I have it that way, I am sending the arguments to a route that I create